# how use string in switch statement in c programming?

Tags: c, string, switch-statement

when i tried to compile this code my compile shows an error saying

> " error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant"

Please tell me where I am doing the mistake.

```
void main()
{
    int i,a,b;
    char c[10];

    printf("\n Input length  of sides in (a,b) format \n");
    scanf("(%d,%d)",&a,&b);

    printf("\n calculate -");

    while(c[10]!="Area\0" || "Perimeter\0")
    {
        scanf("%s",c[10]);  
    }

    switch(c[10])
    {
        case "Area":
            area(a,b);
            break;          
        case "Perimeter":
            perimeter(a,b);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use [strcmp](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) to compare strings.

Comment: First study arrays and pointers. Then study strings. You have to know these things before you attempt to write this program, you can't just "guess" how to write it. To begin with, you must realize that C has no built-in, pre-made string class like other programming languages.

Comment: This code shows lacks of understanding of so much fundamental stuff, that I am voting to close this question a "too broad".

Answer (score 3):

You can not because (as pointed out by @SouravGosh) the labels used in case statement must be an integer constant expression, but if all functions have the same prototype you can use a parallel array of strings and functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int area(int a, int b)
{
    return printf("Area: %d %d\n", a, b);
}

int perimeter(int a, int b)
{
    return printf("Perimeter: %d %d\n", a, b);
}

int main(void)
{
    char buf[256];
    const char *ap[] = {"Area", "Perimeter", NULL}; /* An array of strings */
    int (*fn[])(int, int) = {area, perimeter, NULL}; /* An array of functions */
    const char **pp = ap; /* A pointer to the first element of ap */

    printf("Enter your function name: ");
    scanf ("%s", buf); /* Get users input */
    while (*pp != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(buf, *pp) == 0) { /* Found it */
            fn[pp - ap](1, 2); /* Execute fn() using the same offset of pp */
            break; /* Exit loop */
        }
        pp++; /* Next string */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good code, but how could OP, with his level of knowledge of [tag:c], understand it?...

Comment: @LPs, good point, I will try to explain ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```
scanf("%s",c[10]);
```

is very wrong, you need to write

```
 scanf("%9s", c);
```

That said, The labels used in `case` statement must be *integer* type (integer constant expression). You cannot use string literal as case labels and expect them to perform the string comparison type operation.

As per `C11`, chapter 6.8.4.2

> The expression of each `case` label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of
>   the `case` constant expressions in the same `switch` statement shall have the same value
>   after conversion. [...]

If you have to use the string type user input to determine the case, the best way would be

- Read the input using `fgets()`.
- use `strcmp()` to check for equality.
- set a flag based on the previous comparison result.
- use the flag value in the `switch` and case statements.

Comment: Would love to hear the reasons behind the DV...

Answer (score 0):

[The standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.2) says :

> 6.8.4.2 The switch statement
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 The controlling expression of a switch statement shall have
>   **integer type**.

So you can never use a string (namely a `static` array of `const char`) in a switch statement.

Comment: One might like to add that in fact there is no data type "string" in C.

Comment: @alk Yeah, answer improved

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use string as in "if/else"

```
// switch statement
switch (string) {
  case "C": 
    // code 
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is plain wrong, sorry.